# Error when I try to build APK from Flutter (Android Studio): missing fontVariationSettings

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

I am trying to get my app onto AppCenter for testing among a team, but I'm running into errors in the terminal when I try to run `flutter build apk`

Can anyone help please?

**Terminal**

```
C:\Users\NiallASD\AndroidStudioProjects\EPDSiteDiary>flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter_analytics:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\NiallASD\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\03de50801950aab64f0548832a05435c\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font
VariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\NiallASD\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\03de50801950aab64f0548832a05435c\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcI
ndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter_crashes:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\NiallASD\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\03de50801950aab64f0548832a05435c\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font
VariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\NiallASD\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\03de50801950aab64f0548832a05435c\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcI
ndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\NiallASD\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\03de50801950aab64f0548832a05435c\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font
VariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\NiallASD\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\03de50801950aab64f0548832a05435c\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcI
ndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       7.0s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin appcenter...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    1.3s


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'appcenter'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s


The plugin appcenter could not be built due to the issue above.
```

**res/values/style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.epd.epddiary"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    def appCenterSdkVersion = '3.2.2'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `values.xml` file? Something is off there as the error messge says

Comment: People have encountered the same issue when their application or any of the used dependencies uses min/compile SDK 27. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46881#issuecomment-565187825

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I see no `values.xml`, just `styles.xml` which is in the res/values folder. I added what's in it to the main post.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I had `minSdkVersion 21`, `compileSDKVersion 29` and `targetSdkVersion 28` - changing mini to 28 made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I've added the content of `build.gradle` to my original post, is there anything I need to do with it?